# Django pyinstaller error Import error myapp

Tags: python, django, pyinstaller, importerror

I developped myproject with **Django 1.11.8** and all it's ok
Now I trying to generate the "myproject.exe" file by **pyinstaller 3.4**
This is the
    structure:

```
myproject\
  manage.py   
  myproject\
      settings.py
      urls.py   
  myapp\
    models.py
    views.py
    urls.py
```

**[Settings.py]**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
     ...
     ...
    'myapp',
]
```

**[myapp/views.py]**

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, TemplateView
from myapp.models import ModelOne, ModelTwo
....
```

**[myapp/urls.py]**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from myapp import views
from django.conf import settings
...
```

I receive the error **ImportError** generate by the function:
 get_module_file_attribute(package) where I investigated that the package is "myapp"

like the following:

File "...\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks__init__.py", line 340, in get_module_file_attribute
    raise ImportError
ImportError